# What is the name of the paper that stickers are usually sold on?

Tags: single-word-requests

When we purchase stickers, they usually come stuck to another sheet of paper which it is easy to peel them off of. What is that paper called?

For example, we might say `I just removed the sticker from _____ and then stuck it onto my wall`.

Comment: It's a *backing* card or sheet.

Comment: I've personally never been misunderstood when I say "sticker sheet". As in, "I removed all the stickers from the sticker sheet".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is called a [**release liner, backing paper, carrier or glassine**](https://www.mercianlabels.com/support/self-adhesive-labels/) and the link explains it as follows:

> The **release liner** is commonly made of paper and is silicone coated on 1 side (occasionally 2) to enable the label to be removed cleanly from the liner. Increasingly, especially for some high volume applications where automated applicator machines are used to apply labels at high speed,  plastics are used as a release liner as they do not tear and break as easily as paper.  Of the major industry suppliers, UPM Raflatac are currently advocating Polypropylene (PP) based liners with their ProLiner product, and Avery Dennison prefer Polyester (PET) liners.

[image]

Actually you are referring to a [**peelable paper**](http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/peelable-paper-sticker.html), [**self-adhesive paper**](http://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText=self+adhesive+paper) or [**self-adhesive label/sticker**](http://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText=self+adhesive+label) with a **sticker**, which is a more broadly used *generic* term for them.

You could see what they mean when you visit the links in Alibaba.com.

Comment: The way I'm reading S.I. Paper's explanation, "face paper" is the sticker itself and what the OP is asking about is what S.I. Paper calls the "release base".

Comment: Here's what S.I. Paper says about face paper: "Self Adhesive Labels comprises of four components – face stock, adhesive, silicone coating and liner. The quality of the product depends upon finding the right combination of these components. Face Stock is the face of the label that carries the actual message."

Comment: All good now! :-) +1!

Comment: [release liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_liner) is on wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

I found another nice article on this you might want to read:
[Understanding the Different Layers of a Label](https://www.onlinelabels.com/articles/layers-of-a-label.htm).

We have labels in our company with a so called duplex layer. That is an adhesive layer with adhesive on both sides that is layered between the liner (or backpaper) and facestock.

Comment: Is your company the same as the one writing the linked document?  This smells of spam.

Comment: @Chenmunka Maybe it is a promotion for that company. But if it answers the question, it is a valid answer. Don't you agree?

Comment: @NVZ, Yes, I agree.  That is why I simply ask the question to be sure.

Comment: No, we source stickers for printing at such companies. Many different ones. This just happens to be a link with an explanation that was sent to me by a colleague when I asked about words for sticky label components. We do not manufacture stickers, and I have no affiliation with the products or company that wrote that article.